# What types of energy to account for when calculating the radius of a clasically forbidden region?

Tags: energy

I have two electrons X and Y.

In Y's rest frame, X is approaching it radially from infinity with, say, 70% the speed of light. I want to know what the radius of the classically forbidden region is for electron X, in Y's rest frame.

I know that a classically forbidden region is when the total energy of a particle is less than the potential energy needed to exist there. In this case, the potential energy is dominated by electrostatic potential energy, so we have
$$E_{\text{X-total}}< \frac{k_e\cdot e^2}{r} \iff r<\frac{k_e\cdot e^2}{E_{\text{X-total}}}$$

However, what is $E_{\text{X-total}}$? Is it just the kinetic energy $\frac12 mv^2$ of X? Or do I have to use $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$ or something else?